# scripting: how to cp (or rsync) same files (and filenames) with autorenaming and mantaining .ext

Tags: rsync, rename, cp, file-copy

I want to write a simple bash script (for loop).

After obtaining a list of wanted files, eg:`find /start/* -iname "*.txt" > txt.list`
I'd like to **copy** all of them inside an unique destination with autorenaming and mantaining their extensions.

So, if sources(s) are:

- `/start/sourceA/: name1.txt, name2.txt, name3.mov, ..., namen.txt, ecc...`
- `/start/sourceB/: name1.txt, name2.txt, name4.ods, ..., namen.txt, ecc...`
- `/start/sourceC/: name1.txt, name2.txt, name7.jpg, ..., namen.txt, ecc...`

I'd like to have a single destination with all of the txt files:

- `/end/destination: name1.txt, name1_01.txt, name2.txt, name2_01.txt, ..., namen.txt, ecc...`

Can you please help me and explain how can be done?
`cp` or `rysnc`? <--- Which one will suit best?

Comment: The `--backup` options in `cp` and `rsync` appear to be unable to keep your existing file extensions. I think your best option is to make a symlink of each file locally, rename the symlinks as you like with `rename`, and then use the `--copy-links` option in `rsync` to copy the files using the symlinks rather than the actual files. You can then delete all the symlinks.